# How hard is it for a European to work in Brazil?

Tags: working-visas, brazil

I majored in computer science (.NET software developer) and I would like to move to Brazil to work there for at least a year. I don't mind doing something else. I was working as labourer/farm worker in Melbourne and, recently, I started doing wedding/events videography, so I'm open to anything. How safe/easy would this be for me? Of course, I'm starting to learn the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's definitely possible - I'm Polish and I moved to Brazil last year, but you'll need a lot of patience and strong will :) I also have a Belgian guy in my company and his experience was similar.

To get a temporary working visa for 2 years (Visto Temporario V), probably the only one you can get you need to have work permit from Ministry of Work. After 2 years this can be prolonged for 2 more. Visa can be only issued for a particular company and particular position, if you want to change your job you'll have to apply for a new visa. All the process should be done from your country (maybe except getting an actual visa) because you'll need to visit some places like your Ministry of Foreign Affairs.

1. Start learning Portuguese

   I live in center of Sao Paulo which is supposed to be one of more "international" places around here and I have hard time finding anyone speaking English outside my job and maybe museums and good restaurants. It'll help a lot during recruiting. Probably you'll be able to find a job speaking only in English, but you'll still need it in your everyday life, while registering as a foreigner etc. I lived in Portugal before which made it much easier for me, but still the difference between European and Brazilian Portuguese is quite big
2. Choose a city

   In SP there's plenty of jobs but the city is less attractive (it's really good for life, plenty of nightlife, amazing parties, but not much to see). Rio de Janeiro might be more difficult and it's quite dangerous for foreigners. Places like Florianopolis, Curitiba are safe and beautiful, but don't have too many offers.
3. Find a job

   As a Software Developer you're lucky because the demand is high, at least in SP :) With other professions it's difficult to get hired as a foreigner because the process is long and the company has to be really motivated to hire you. There are plenty of offers on LinkedIn where you can apply, just be prepared that everyone will ask "why the hell you want to move to Brazil" - I love this country, but not all the people here agree. If you tell them you want to move only for a year they might be not happy, for you it might not be the best too because there are some work benefits (like holidays) which you only get after a year. Read about the work law here because it's quite different than in Europe (rather better for the employee). Taxes are higher.
4. Get work permit from Ministry of Work in Brazil

   When you get a job your company has to issue an invitation for you, and get your permit to come to Brazil. They'll also have to pay around 300-500 EUR in total for all the documentation and translations. This will require around 6-8 documents which you'll need to get authorized in your Ministry of Foreign Affairs according to a conference about Apostille which Brasil signed recently. It's around 15 EUR / document. You'll need birth certificate, master diploma or documentation of your last positions and several other which depend on every case. This may take 1-3 months because the Ministry will keep asking for new documents, signatures and approvals.
5. Get a visa!

   With work permit you can apply for a visa. It usually costs 100 USD and takes up to a week to issue.
6. After arriving there, the actual bureaucratic fun begins

   So I'm here for three months and during that time I had to visit many various offices to get all the numbers needed to buy anything, get monthly cellular plan (I only managed to do that two days ago) etc. Every document needs two other, no one really knows where to get them, so you have to get used to everything taking a long time.

Having said all that about bureaucracy I still think it's worth it, it's an amazing country, people are lovely and you can easily travel to more beautiful places on weekends :)

Some people are coming here and working on tourist visa, but I don't recommend here because a) it's illegal, b) without work permit you can't do most simple things in life.

Comment: Let me know if you need more info about any section, I can add it later :)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer, appreciate it.  People and the place is the reason why I want to move there. Do you think learning Spanish instead of Portuguese (at least initially) will still be beneficial? It's hard to find Portuguese here and Spanish would also be more useful to me as I'd like to travel around S. America

Comment: @Kuba Hello Kuba. Why did you choose Brazil?